# Help with CMS PHP/MySQL project for managing jobs/tickets?

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, lamp

I have experience in php but not with large scale projects.
i am looking for a sample CMS PHP(preferably using the LAMP stack) for managing tickets, to learn from. Here are the functionalists I want:

1. Login (with security)
2. Users (designers,supervisors, and clients) can login and upload/review/download jobs.
3. Clients upload jobs with files and description
4. Supervisors assign jobs to designers
5. Designers download jobs, and upload them when done
6. Clients then download finished jobs

Any help will be useful. Links, guidelines, projects, articles, tutorials, or books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) is a very well established open source ticket tracking system.  I use it daily at work and it offers a high level of flexibility and is relatively easy to customize.

It allows you to generally attach files to tickets which would fulfill your requirement of uploading/downloading the files for the ticket.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this site which has a list of open sourced ticket tracking systems, http://www.opensourcehelpdesklist.com/. Bugzilla is also on it

Answer (score 0):

I can advise dotProject. It is written in PHP and it's code is quite understandable. Take a look: http://www.dotproject.net/